# ASP.NET web API handling dynamic connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a project where it is an absolute requirement that each client is on a separate database. My design is to use a class that builds the connection string from the `userId`. There is a base controller class that will check if the database connection is in the Session variable and if not will build and store it. Is this a good approach from a security and performance standpoint?

```
public abstract class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    protected BaseApiController()
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionWrapper.ConnectionString)) return;

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            var connectionString = CustomerConnectionString.GetConnectionString(userId);
            SessionWrapper.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

    }
}
```